# MYSQL JOIN. How to join only first match? (Join limit 1)

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with 1 000 000 records. (`t1`)
have "select query" which are very fast and returns me a single column result of IDs. (in result I have only unique IDs. For example : 1,2,5,10,.. **(have no-repeating values)**)

EXPLAIN SELECT SHOWS ME ONLY type `index` and `ref` (perfect query :) )

But I need to filter this results from records by this way:
inner join with other 1 000 000 table (`t2`)

```
ON (`t1`.`some_column_id` = `t2`.`ref_id` AND `t1`.`user_id` = 4)
```

It shows me all matches of `t1`.`some_column_id` = `t2`.`ref_id`
Even when I Use

```
GROUP BY `t1`.`some_column_id` AND/OR LIMIT of 30 ROWS
```

it fails mysql server

What will you propose to do to limit this INNER JOIN with only with first match?

Comment: Would you specify your RDMS, please. Also, the question is not clear, would you please show a whole query?

Comment: @NBR Have a look at the tags and you'll know.

Comment: And what do you mean by the "first match"? What's the order?

Comment: Using a `SELECT [..] FROM t2 JOIN [subquery]`, where a subquery selects only one row from `t1` should be quick I think.

Comment: I think about that, but how fast will this query works if subquery returns 0..5000 records?

Comment: @NBR It means if I have in first result [1,2,3,4,5..N] and will join table which have records with few values of "5" it will return all 5=5 joined combinations. I need to limit by 1 match

Comment: Please add the query and the execution plan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the information available, I was able to find this solution. This will probably take some time to execute on such a large database. I am still looking for some better alternative.

Assuming that the field '`some_column_id`' or '`ref_id`' is not unique. First make them unique by selecting exactly one `id` (primary key) with some aggregate function such as `MIN()`. Use it like this:

```
SELECT tTwo.* FROM (SELECT notUnique, MIN(id) AS min FROM t GROUP BY notUnique) tOne INNER JOIN t AS tTwo ON (tTwo.id=tOne.min)
```

Note that the above query is applied to only one table to make the given column unique.

After applying it for the tables as required, you will have to simply do this

```
SELECT * FROM t1_unique INNER JOIN t2_unique ON (t1_unique.some_column_id = t2_unique.ref_id)
```

where `t1_unique` and `t2_unique` will be having unique values for `some_column_id` and `ref_id` respectively.